# Update EF 4 Feature CTP 4 Detached POCO

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, poco

I am trying to update a detached POCO w/ EF 4 CTP 4.

My domain class looks like this:

```
public class User {
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Required, DisplayName("First Name")]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  [Required, DisplayName("Last Name")]
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  [ConcurrencyCheckAttribute, Timestamp]
  public byte[] DataVersion { get; set; }
}
```

In the repository I have the following:

```
public void SaveUser(User user) {
  if (user.Id > 0) {
   dbContext.Users.Attach(user);
  }
  else {
   dbContext.Users.Add(user);
  }
  dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

dbContext inherits from DbContext.

I am able to do inserts fine, but the attach doesn't work. I run Sql Profiler, and no sql is sent for the update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it figured out....

In the dbContext class I added a method that marks the entity as modified.

```
public void MarkAsModified(object entity) {
  base.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
}
```

My repository method now looks like this

```
public void SaveUser(User user) {
  if (user.Id > 0) {
    dbContext.Users.Attach(user);
    dbContext.MarkAsModified(user);
  }
  else {
    dbContext.Users.Add(user);
  }

  dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: hi. I've searched now for long time just for "updating detached object in linq" and both lines are working now 'db.UserProfileSet.Attach(User)` `db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(User, EntityState.Modified)
`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is basically doing the same thing, but what I've done is in your User Repository have a method called `GetForUpdate` or something similar:

```
public User GetForUpdate(int id)
{
    var u = new User();
    u.Id = id;
    dbContext.Users.Attach(u);
    return u;
}
```

Then when you want to "update" a user with a known id:

```
var user = userRepo.GetForUpdate(id);
user.Name = "John Doe";
user.Username = "john.doe";
userRepo.SaveUser(user);
```

Attaching the user and *then* modifying properties will automatically set the `EntityState` as `Modified`.

HTH

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the tip. The only issue with this is I am using MVC, and would like to take advantage of model binding. In your example, I would need to call the repo.GetForUpdate then UpdateModel and then Save. But it is good to know there are alternatives.

Comment: [Scott suggests to use the `UpdateModel()` method](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimpleCodeFirstWithEntityFramework4MagicUnicornFeatureCTP4.aspx) in the controller but obviously that's not applicable here. I think this `Attach` might be broken or incomplete?